# c# Do I have to specify name for a new class instance?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I'm making a simple game in unity and have a small uncretainity you could help me with:
do I have to name the new instance of a class?
for example:

```
public class CreateCharacter : MonoBehaviour {

public string charname;

public CreateCharacter (string charname)
{
    this.charname = charname;
    //does all the stuff needed
}}
```

I want to run this from another script:

```
int e = data.Length - 1;
            if (e > 0)
            {
                new CreateCharacter(data[e]);
                e--;
            }
```

data is a string array and CreateCharacter will store the new Character object in a list of such objects, so I can accss it later. My question is:
Do I have to write:

```
CreateCharacter SomeName = new ChreateCharacter
```

for the code to run? or is simple

```
new Class (constructor)
```

enough?

Comment: If you don't actually need to have an object instance constructed and used then that behavior should be in a static method.

Comment: How would I go about that static method?

Comment: If this class has to inherit from MonoBehaviour: Don't use a constructor and `new`.

Comment: @Bronsoner You create a static method, then put the code from `//does all the stuff needed` into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is poor practice to new something and not toss it in a variable, that code WILL compile and run just fine. Additionally, is there a reason you have a class called CreateCharacter? Instead of a function that returns an actual character given the data?

Comment: I'm doing a cascade of functions to create objects from lists - So Buildings initialize creation fo Characters, Characters initialize other stuff and so forth - all by sucking in data from txt files. Perhaps thats not optimal (I'm a noob), but helps me logically keep track of stuff happening. If there is a simpler way to do it, I'd be happy to learn.

Comment: I think you would be better off simply using a cascade of functions as you describe, but you might new a building, which might new some characters which is fine, or maybe Character has a static function called CreateCharacter:  Character.CreateCharacter(someData)
Also what is the format of these text files? Json? something else? You could use JSON  and json.net to create the character directly.

Comment: just a simple txt file - I use a char delimiter to make a data array and read it, so I can get all neccesary data for a Character object constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It won't cause the program to die using without storing it.

`new CreateCharacter(data[e]);`

but yes, you want to store it so you can call methods on it like

`CreateCharacter char = new CreateCharacter(string);`

`char.methodName();`

Your other option is to put the code you are trying to execute in a `static method` because it seems that the code you are running in the constructor is not dependent on the instance of the class `CreateCharacter`.

Comment: The premise of the question is that the code that he needs it to run is in the constructor (presumably it causes side effects) and not in other methods of that class.  It's typically poor practice, but certainly doable.

Comment: @Servy Since his class is called `CreateCharacter` for Unity I'm 99% certain that he wants to store the character in a variable.

Comment: Well he's pretty confident that he doesn't need it for anything, so while it may be the case that it would be better to design the class so that is the case, it doesn't appear to be the case with its current design.

Comment: @Servy I added your suggestion of a static method to the answer. Feel free to edit or elaborate as you please

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to call the constructor by itself like you stated.  However, do keep in mind that the newly created object will immediately fall out of scope and be deallocated after the constructor is done.  So depending on what's included in "// does all the stuff needed", it could -potentially- crash your app (although it would be unlikely).

As stated in other answers, it is a best practice in both readability and functionality to assign the newly created object to a variable, even if only for the scope of that for loop.

Comment: It'd be *very* hard to crash the application as a result of the object leaving scope.  It'd likely require unsafe code.  The whole point of having a GC is that it will never collect anything that could ever be referenced by other (managed) code.  Also note just storing it in a variable and then never using it wouldn't change anything; the GC is allowed to see that it's not being read from and collect it early anyway.

Comment: Let me add something: I want to run CreateCharacter, that takes data from a file (specified by constructor), creates a new Character object, adds it to a list of Characters and I can do all stuff with this Character object. So is this gonna run just fine?

Answer (score 1):

If you use

> new Class (constructor)

it is anonymous object and it does the job. This king of object is used whenever the object is not referenced from other places of your code and its benefit is that you are not supposed to find an appropriate name for that.